# Quick casting shortcut in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, casting, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

Is there a fast way to cast an object/primitive to other objects/primitives in eclipse. I am looking for something like a quick try/catch block: You select the block and press `Ctrl + Alt + Z` to quickly surround the block with a try/catch.

So, for the quick casting you select the block again, you hit the keys and type the name of the object quickly with autocompletion and voila you made the cast.

I know this exists via `Ctrl + 1` when an auto-correction is available but I also would like to do it seperately.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually have this *code template* set up for my Eclipse. Here's how you can configure it.

Open the `Preferences` dialog by going to `Windows > Preferences` and then navigate to `Java > Editor > Templates`. Click on `New...` here to create a new *Code Template* as shown below.

[image: Code Template]

Now, within the Java file editor, select the *Object* you want to type cast and hit `Ctrl + Space`.

[image: Ctrl + Space drop-down]

Invoke the code template and you'll get something like

```
[type] [new_name] = ([type]) new ArrayList<String>();
```

where the `[]` indicate that type can be specified using auto-complete.

There's also a default `cast` template available which can be invoked by typing `cast` and then hitting `Ctrl + Space`. The difference is that it doesn't support selections but lets you specify the target object through auto-complete. I find both the variants useful.

```
[type] [new_name] = ([type]) [name];
```

Comment: This sounds really useful. I have defined the template as you mentioned but I cannot invoke it. I can use the default cast template by writin cast and Ctlr+Space. But I cannot see yours when I select and hit Ctlr + Space (I also tried to hit it several times since it says ctrl+space to show template proposals)

Comment: The selection must be a valid Object. For example, in my answer I had selected the complete `new ArrayList<String>()`. It wouldn't show up for a partial selection like just `new` unless the selection also happens to be a valid object reference.

Comment: Yes, my selection is a valid object for example: Query query = `new Query(rawQuery)`; or just `rawQuery` inside that.

Comment: It didn't work because `new Query()` is already assigned and `rawQuery` cannot be assigned as it's an argument. The selection should result in valid Java after its replaced with the template. For example, if you delete the `query` reference and then select `new Query()` it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse provides a way to create shortcuts for quick fixes.

You can create a shortcut that "presses ctrl+1 and then select add cast option". Using this approach, you dont even have to select the block, just step over it, like when using ctrl+1, plus you are using IDE existing option.

It can be done in the menu `Window > Preferences > General > Keys`  and then search for `Quick Fix - Add Cast` command. Assign your own binding and done! (can't upload image because of my reputation).

PD: In my case, there were two `Quick Fix - Add Cast` commands and just one of them did the trick, you may have to try both.